# Installing Pillow on FreeBSD based shell hosting

Tags: python, pip, freebsd, python-imaging-library

I'm struggling with Pillow on my shell hosting based on FreeBSD. 
Running `pip install Pillow` (inside virtualenv, if it does matter) results with this:

http://justpaste.it/ich2

I have absolutely no idea what's wrong. Someone knows the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, running installer with `MAX_CONCURRENCY=1 pip install pillow` did the trick.
Maybe it will be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested way is to install from packages; they often contain patches that fix various system-specific problems.  Doing "pkg search pillow" shows that you can do "pkg install py27-pillow".